# Getting rid of "forcing GC OFF because OBJC_DISABLE_GC is set"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, garbage-collection

When I run my tests, I get lines like this:

```
objc[8845]: GC: forcing GC OFF because OBJC_DISABLE_GC is set
```

It also pollutes the output of the subprocesses that I run. How do I get rid of it? My project is built with ARC, so I certainly don't want garbage collection.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? Also, please edit your question to include the full source of the “Run Script” phase of your test bundle target.

Comment: Xcode 4.6.3. The full source is: `"${SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DIR}/Tools/RunUnitTests"`